# Div height in small resolution is not same

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, so in laptop and desktop div working fine like:

[image]

but in Ipad or mobile, it became like:

[image]

HTML code:

```
  <div class="thumbnail_container">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
           <h3>First Div Test</h3>
              <p>

              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
           <h3>Second Div Test</h3>
              <p>

              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS code to manage div display:

```
    .thumbnail_container .thumbnail
   {
     border-color: white;   
       color: black;
       width: 100%;
       padding-right: 0px;
       padding-left: 0px;
       padding-top: 0px;
       border-color: lightseagreen;

   }


   .thumbnail_container
   {
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: 30px;
   }


    .thumbnail span  
   {
      left:0; right:0;
       margin: auto;
   }

   .caption > p
   {
       color: black;
       width: 100%;
       margin-top: 0px;
       text-align: justify;

   }
```

How to make all div height same in any screen resolution?

Comment: Can you include some CSS? It looks like your content is being pushed down, but we have no way of determining by what.

Comment: css code is added to main question

Comment: Height depents on the content.

Comment: guys, please check provided answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3gdvugeg/) and comment if it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `class="thumbnail_container"` to `class="thumbnail_container equal"`
 and then copy  the following code and paste it

```
   /*make thumbnail div height equal */
   @media screen and (min-width: 768px) 
   {
     .equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] 
     {  
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex:1 1 auto;
       }
      }
```

[working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jLzj5w9t/)

Answer (score 0):

Just give `display: flex;` to `.thumbnail_container` and `height: 100%;` to `.thumbnail` will make equal height.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gdvugeg/)**

Comment: still changing its height based in contents

Comment: @SaifManea Have you checked my fiddle? It's working fine

Comment: try to minimize it, you will observe that div's height are not same

Comment: Check this image in minimum width i am seeing. http://i.stack.imgur.com/5B2Ar.png

Comment: I checked in three devices and it shows like [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4bdQ6.png